# How to link a slider value to the FontSize of a textblock and store that value in a ApplicationData variable

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, slider, windows-store-apps

I hope you can help me to solve my problem. I have a simple metro app. A textblock named myTextBlock is placed in the HomePageView page. This is its xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource timeStyle}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="300"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="11,55,3,0"  ManipulationMode="All">
```

This is the LoadState in the HomePageView code behind:

```
 protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            try
            {
                double? myTextBlockValue = (double?)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["myTextBlockSize"];
                if (myTextBlockValue != null)
                {
                    myTextBlock.FontSize = (double)myTextBlockValue;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

I built a Settings pane (charm bar -> settings -> settings) named SettingsPage in which a slider named timeSlider is placed. This is its xaml:

```
<Slider x:Name="timeSlider" Width="257" Minimum="1" Maximum="600" Loaded="timeSlider_Loaded" ValueChanged="timeSlider_ValueChanged" />
```

And these are the slider Loaded and ValueChanged methods placed in the SettingsPage codebehind:

```
 private void timeSlider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sliderIstance = sender as Slider;
            double? storedSize = (double?)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["myTextBlockSize"];
            if (storedSize != null && storedSize != 1)
                sliderIstance.Value = (double)storedSize;
            else
                sliderIstance.Value = 300;
        }

        private void timeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sliderIstance = sender as Slider;
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["myTextBlockSize"] = sliderIstance.Value as double?;
            var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            _Frame.Navigate(_Frame.Content.GetType());
            _Frame.GoBack();
        }
```

You can download the complete solution here on my skydrive: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B721133DC03E67C!7350

In this way, I linked the fontsize property of myTextBlock (in the HomePageView page) to the value property of the slider (in the SettingsPage page), so the user can change this property at runtime. Also, this property is stored in the myTextBlockSize ApplicationData variable to preserve its value when the app is closed and reopened.

The solution works but THE PROBLEM is: when I enter the settings pane (charm bar -> settings -> settings) and change the textblock fontsize property through the slider, then I come back to the homepageview and reopen the settings pane, the fontsize property is reinitialized to its original value so it doesn't keep the previous (user selected) value.
Can you fix my code please? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add one condition `if (sliderIstance.Value != 1)` in `timeSlider_ValueChanged` event

```
private void timeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var sliderIstance = sender as Slider;
    if (sliderIstance.Value != 1)
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["myTextBlockSize"] = sliderIstance.Value as double?;
    var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    _Frame.Navigate(_Frame.Content.GetType());
    _Frame.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You got the solution. It was so simple! :)